# Comparing an element in two different List that are different objects

Tags: java

I will post my code, but just change the names. I'll add comments when I can add more info.

```
List<AbstractA> foo = bar.getFoo; // This returns an ArrayList<E> with two objects. Each object has an ID and Price. 

List<Name> names = null;
try{
   names = someClass.getNames(); // This returns an ArrayList<E> with 10 Name objects. Each one has an ID, name, description
}catch(Exception e){
   Log.warn(e);
}
```

My main goal is compare the two lists. I have...

```
Iterator<Name> object = names.iterator();
while(object.hasNext()){
   Name j = object.next(); // assign next name
   System.out.println("j.getId(): " + j.getId()); // This provides me the Id
   System.out.println("foo.contains(j.getId()) " + foo.contains(j.getId())); // Keeps spitting out false but I want it to be true

   if(foo.contains(j.getId())){
      object.remove(); //remove name out of Names list
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if this makes a lot of sense of what I am trying to do. 
There are two beans in this program representing foo and name. So they are different objects and I think that may be the issue.

Any suggestions? Sorry if this is VERY vague...

My main question is, if I want to compare an element in these two Lists, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List.contains(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) uses [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for its comparisons:

> More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

equals() doesn't require the two objects to be the same class, so you can override it like this:

```
class Name {

    // Stuff

    @Override
    bool equals(Object other) {
        if(other instanceof Name) {
            Name otherName = (Name)other;
            // Compare this and otherName, return true or false depending
            // on if they're equal
        } else if (other instanceof AbstractA) {
            AbstractA otherAbstractA = (AbstractA)other;
            // Compare this and otherAbstractA, return true or false depending
            // on if they're equal
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You probably want to override equals() for both, so that a.equals(b) == b.equals(a).

If you're finding yourself doing this a lot, it may be that an abstract class that they both implement will help.

Comment: Would this be in the class I am performing this code in, or the "bar" and "SomeClass" class?

Comment: @envinyater The two classes you want to be comparable. So whatever type goes in `foo` (`AbstractA` in your example) and whatever you're comparing it to (j which is a `Name`), or just override AbstractA.getEquals() to handle Strings if you only want to compare ID's.

Comment: Really? I doubt its a good idea for to claim to be `equal` to a `String` like this. Also see Josh Bloch's comment about being equal to even a subsclass: [The biggest disadvantage is the fact that you get two objects that appear equal (because they are equal on all the fields) but they are not equal because they are of different classes. This can cause surprising behavior.](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch17.html)

Comment: Yeah I agree that making it comparable to a String is probably a bad idea. I don't see the problem with subclasses being equal though. Isn't that what you'd want?

Answer (score 1):

> foo.contains(j.getId()))

`foo` is `List<AbstractA>` and `j.getId()` is (I guess) a `String`. Since [`List.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) uses the `equals` method this will never be `true` unless you define `AbstractA.equals` in a strange way.

Best would be to write your own method to iterate through the list and compare. You can use `Guava` but it would be overkill for just this

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have two Maps instead of Lists.

for `foo`:

```
key: id
value: Object of AbstractA
```

for `names`:

```
key: id
value: Name object
```

then you could compare the keys (id in your case)

I hope I understood you right.